# htaccess page does not redirect properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, opencart

I am using opencart in my ecommerce. And I want to setup an htaccess that will redirect to the admin panel.

Here's my current setup for the htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 302 .* http://localhost/dev_beta/flaxcms/admin/
```

I want to redirect

```
http://localhost/dev_beta/flaxcms
```

To

```
http://localhost/dev_beta/flaxcms/admin/
```

Can you help me about this? Or if Opencart related is there a way so that only the admin panel is accessible and not the store front end?

Ok thats all I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Ok I update my index.php and I think my code for this is kinda dirty but it solves my issue:

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

if($actual_link == 'http://localhost/dev_beta/flaxcms/') {
    header('Location: http://localhost/dev_beta/flaxcms/admin');
    exit;
}
```

I don't think that it is a good idea.

Comment: Is that the only account? Or are you pattern matching to change all URLs of the form http://localhost/dev_beta/* to http://localhost/dev_beta/*/admin/?

Comment: Sorry I did not get you question. Ok what I only want is instead of opening to front end. The user simple redirect to admin. Sorry I am not good enough in doing htaccess things.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
RewriteEngine on 
Redirect 302 /dev_beta/flaxcms$ http://localhost/dev_beta/flaxcms/admin/
```

Comment: Still cant redirect to admin :(

Comment: What's your document root? If it is `dev_beta` you need to replace `/dev_beta/flaxcms$` with `/flaxcms$`

Answer (score 1):

Create a `dev_beta/.htaccess` if it doesn't exist and place this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^flaxcms/?$ /dev_beta/flaxcms/admin/ [L,NC,R=302]
```

You must clear your browser cache before testing this change.